# Codeigniter Paging DB Results Issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue getting some paging code working with a query I am trying to run in one of my models.

I'll get to the issue in a moment

## Code

```
public function current($page = 0){
    if($_POST){
        
    }else{
        $this->db->start_cache();
        $this->db->select('b.orderID, b.orderTracking, b.orderShipped, b.orderShippedOn, b.orderPaid, b.orderPaidOn, 
                         (Select Top 1 c.payTranID From vwSelectOrderPayments c where c.orderID = b.orderID Order By c.payPosted Desc) as TranID');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->from('vwSelectOrders b');
        $this->db->where('b.orderPaid', 1);
        $this->db->where('b.orderPaidOn >', date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-300 days')));
        $this->db->stop_cache();
        $total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results();
        $this->db->order_by('b.orderPaidOn', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit(12, $page);
        $qry = $this->db->get();
        $rs = $qry->result_array();
        $this->db->flush_cache();
        $config['base_url'] = '/orders/current';
        $config['per_page'] = 12;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
        $config['first_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-left page_num"></span>';
        $config['last_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right page_num"></span>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="page_num bold">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['next_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-right page_num"></span>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-left page_num"></span>';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="page_num">';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
    $data['rs'] = $rs;
    $data['current_page'] = $page;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/orders/current', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Displays the 1st page without issue, however, upon clicking on of the paging links, I am presented with a CI Database Error: `The multi-part identifier "b.orderID" could not be bound.`

The query produced is:

```
SELECT b.orderID,b.orderTracking,b.orderShipped,b.orderShippedOn,b.orderPaid,b.orderPaidOn,
    (Select Top 1 c.payTranID From vwSelectOrderPayments c where c.orderID = b.orderID Order By c.payPosted Desc) as TranID 
FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY b.orderPaidOn desc) AS 
    CI_offset_row_number, b.orderID, b.orderTracking, b.orderShipped, b.orderShippedOn, b.orderPaid, b.orderPaidOn, 
        (Select Top 1 c.payTranID From vwSelectOrderPayments c where c.orderID = b.orderID Order By c.payPosted Desc) as TranID 
    FROM vwSelectOrders b 
    WHERE b.orderPaid = 1 AND b.orderPaidOn > '05/21/2013' ) AS A 
WHERE A.CI_offset_row_number BETWEEN (13) AND (24)
```

With which I have attempted to run in MS SQL Manager, and was presented with:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderTracking" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderShipped" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderShippedOn" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderPaid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.orderPaidOn" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "b.orderID" could not be bound.
```

Now, I am using almost the exact same code in another model, and this issue does not occur.  The difference between the 2 is the view I am querying.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fields with alias name `A`.

Instead of using `b.orderID`, `b.orderTracking` .... You should use as `A.orderID`,`A.orderTracking`.

change your code :

```
$this->db->select('A.orderID, A.orderTracking, A.orderShipped, A.orderShippedOn,A.orderPaid, A.orderPaidOn, 
                         (Select Top 1 c.payTranID From vwSelectOrderPayments c where c.orderID = b.orderID Order By c.payPosted Desc) as TranID');
```